# How to explore the Spring context of a Server in DEBUG view

Tags: java, eclipse, spring

When I debug a web app with an application server (**JBoss**) under **Eclipse**, I would like a way to explore the **Spring context beans**, "live", without having to "pause" or anything.

This would allow me to get the services and fire some methods (cache flush and so on).

It would be very handy.

Do you know a tool, plugin or simply a trick to achieve that ?

Comment: Does it need to be in DEBUG mode?  Have you considered using JMX?

Comment: In order to invoke a method, you need to have a thread to invoke it on. Which means that you have to "pause" something. JMX is definitely the way to go here, exposing appropriate attributes/operations.

Comment: Thks, I was not aware of JMX at all.
I think I will consider it in my application.
Could you add your comment as an answer so I can accept it ?

Answer (score 0):

Would you explain more about "I would like a way to explore the Spring context beans, "live", without having to "pause" or anything." I will be easier to expalin more.If you want to monitor then JMX can be best.Jmx is based on management bean concept.When you define management bean you can view it either VisualVm oR jconsole tool.The best part of jmx is that in run time you can change the value of management  bean without restaring the server.Suppose you defined a static variable a=10.If after it is deployed in server you need to change its value to 20 then via visualVM tool you can change its value to 20.You do not need to recompile and deploy .Sprin g provides support for JMX.